# What is the competitive ratio of a $d$-way associative LRU cache?

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, online-algorithms

In a caching problem, items arrive online, and the algorithm needs to decide which elements to keep in the cache. If the current item is not cached, we pay a penalty of $1$.

It is well known that for a $k$-sized LRU cache has a competitive ratio of $k$ and that no deterministic algorithm can do better than that.

Consider the following (randomized) algorithm:

1. We choose a random hash function that maps items into $\{1,\ldots,d\}$.
2. Whenever we see a request, we hash it into one of $d$ LRU caches (of size $k/d$ each).

> **What is the competitive ratio of this limited associativity LRU variant?**

---

It seems that if $k\gg d$, we can use a balls-and-bins analysis to show that an input that consists of round robin of $k$ items will give a $k/d (1-o(1))$ lower bound.

- Is this tight?
- What about other cases?

Comment: No, it's not competitive as is.  Consider the case of k items that are requested repeatedly in round-robin fashion.  Clearly OPT has constant cost.  But with positive probability one of your d caches will receive more than k/d items, and so will fault repeatedly.  (I guess you need to use a slightly larger cache than OPT.  It seems difficult to ensure that your hash function partitions any set of k items into d groups of size k/d.)

Comment: @NealYoung - good point.